# ActiveMQ Artemis scheduled message

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am following [this example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis-examples/tree/6958316d39b01f67add3c2f90a1bf75f62c39020/examples/features/standard/scheduled-message) which is supposed to send a scheduled message to a JMS queue in ActiveMQ Artemis. I am connecting to a Docker ActiveMQ Artemis version 2.32.0 using:

```
ConnectionFactory cf = new JmsConnectionFactory("amqp://localhost:5672?jms.username=artemis&jms.password=artemis");
```

But the messages is sent immediately as shown below.

```
Sent message: This is a scheduled message message which will be delivered in 5 sec.
Time of send: Thu, 8 Feb 2024 13:45:21
Received message: This is a scheduled message message which will be delivered in 5 sec.
Time of receive: Thu, 8 Feb 2024 13:45:21
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the example you're following is using the *core* protocol. However, your code is using the AMQP protocol instead.

Typically with AMQP if you want to send a scheduled message to ActiveMQ Artemis you'd use one of the following message *annotations* [as noted in the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/amqp.html#amqp-scheduling-message-delivery):

- `x-opt-delivery-time`: The specified value must be a positive long corresponding to the time the message should be made available for delivery (in milliseconds).
- `x-opt-delivery-delay`: The specified value must be a positive long corresponding to the amount of milliseconds after the broker receives the given message before it should be made available for delivery.

However, since your using Qpid **JMS** which supports JMS 2 you can use the [`setDeliveryDelay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#setDeliveryDelay-long-) method on your `MessageProducer`. There's no need to set a provider-specific property.

You could, of course, also switch to the core protocol just like the example does.

Comment: In the ActiveMQ UI, Is it expected to see the message count to be incremented for scheduled message but when I browse the queue, I do not see the scheduled messages? Thx

Comment: Yes, it is expected that the message count will increase but you won't be able to see the message in a browser because technically speaking the message is not yet on the queue. It won't be on the queue until the scheduled time.

Comment: If you really want to see the scheduled messages you can invoke the `listScheduledMessagesAsJSON` management operation on the appropriate queue control.